# Facebook share button sometimes displaying

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-share

I'm trying to load a facebook share button but sometimes it will display (randomly) and sometimes (most of the time) it wont. 
I looked in the console and sometimes it loads the content and sometimes it just displays the div.

[code when not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbkUp.png)

[code when working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoV0c.png)

html

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=300339200130883"; 
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

javascript

```
     getPopContent.innerHTML += '<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+this.id+'" data-layout="button_count"></div>';
```

Comment: Sounds like a runtime issue. That means, that the DOM elements are not completely loaded, when you execute your script. When you can use JQuery, then try to add `$( document ).ready(function() {
    YOUR JAVASCRIPT
});` So it will be executed, when your DOM has loaded.

Comment: I'm not using Jquery, pure JavaScript

Comment: Then put you `<script>` Tag down to the bottom of your HTML page. This may help.

Comment: Still sometimes displays it and sometimes it doesnt

Comment: In all browsers or do you test it in only one browser?

Comment: only tested it in chrome